# Activity.order("created_at desc").where(How to include current_user & following_ids?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, feed

This shows on the feed all the activities by the users you are following, but I want it to include the posts from the **users you are following + your own**.

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc").where(user_id: current_user.following_ids).paginate(:page => params[:page]) # If I take out following_ids it will list out only the activities from the current_user. We need both.
    end
```

**activity.rb**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.per_page = 20
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :habit
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :quantified
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true

  def conceal
    trackable.conceal
  end

  def page_number
    (index / per_page.to_f).ceil
  end

private

  def index
    Activity.order(created_at: :desc).index self
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
  acts_as_taggable
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :activities
  has_many :activity_likes
  has_many :liked_activities, through: :activity_likes, class_name: 'Activity',   source: :liked_activity
  has_many :liked_comments, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'Comment', source: :liked_comment
  has_many :valuation_likes
  has_many :habit_likes
  has_many :goal_likes
  has_many :quantified_likes
  has_many :comment_likes
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :habits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :levels
  has_many :combine_tags
  has_many :valuations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
  has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :quantifieds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :results, through: :quantifieds
  has_many :notes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :habits, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantifieds, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, unless: -> { from_omniauth? }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  scope :publish, ->{ where(:conceal => false) }
  User.tag_counts_on(:tags)

  def count_mastered
    @res = habits.reduce(0) do |count, habit|
    habit.current_level == 6 ? count + 1 : count
    end
  end

  def count_challenged
    @challenged_count = habits.count - @res
  end

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.password = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
        user.email = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join+"@mailinator.com"
        user.save!
      end
    end

  def self.koala(auth)
    access_token = auth['token']
    facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
    facebook.get_object("me?fields=name,picture")
  end


  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Forgets a user. NOT SURE IF I REMOVE
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

   # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  def good_results_count
    results.good_count
  end

  # Follows a user.
  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end

private 

    def from_omniauth? 
      provider && uid 
    end

      # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email 
      self.email = email.downcase unless from_omniauth? 
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
end
```

Please let me know if you need any further explanation or code to help you help me =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the `current_user` to the `following_ids`

`where(user_id: current_user.following_ids + [current_user.id])`

Comment: Thanks abm for some reason it needed to be user_id instead of just ids :)